# Remove Topic Id and .html from URL using Rewrite Rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect some broken urls. Currently, they appear like this:

`https://www.Example.com/showthread.php/72531-palms-down-dumbbell-wrist-curl-over-bench.html`

the **CORRECT URL** should be:

`https://www.Example.com/community/topic/palms-down-dumbbell-wrist-curl-over-a-bench/`

Note the Removal of:

`72531-`

After multiple tries I finally came up with this one:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]+-([^&]+)
        RewriteRule ^/?showthread.php/(.*)\.html$ https://www.example.com/community/topic/$1 [L,R=301]`

but the problem is that it returns the link like this:

```
    https://www.example.com/community/topic/72531-palms-down-dumbbell-wrist-curl-over-bench
```

How do I remove the `72531-` part of the url?? I've tried about 60 different combinations and none of them work properly.

Comment: Your url doesn't appear to contain a `QUERY_STRING` . Then why are you using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]+-([^&]+)` ?

Comment: because it doesn't matter if it's there or not and the rules below it use it. I've tried it both ways, with AND without the  `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]+-([^&]+)`